# Keras CNTK Model Command Not Working (Works with TensorFlow)

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, cntk

I'm in the process of setting up and using Keras with both TensorFlow and CNTK to compare and learn both systems. I've successfully set up the TensorFlow piece, but when I switch to CNTK I get an error and I'm a bit at a loss as to how to fix it. It looks like the issue is with the Model command but if I rework that to fit the CNTK approach I'll have to keep multiple versions of my code, which defeats part of the point of Keras; is there a way to do this natively in Keras to be compatible with both? The code is the third section of [this](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html).

I'm getting a dll error, as shown here:

```
C:\Users\shaff\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\KerasTensor\python.exe "C:/Users/shaff/LRZ Sync+Share/Deep Learning for Computer Vision/FinalProject/LearningKeras/KerasCatDog/KerasCatDogPart3.py"
Using CNTK backend
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shaff\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\KerasTensor\lib\site-packages\cntk\cntk_py.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\shaff\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\KerasTensor\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cntk._cntk_py'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/shaff/LRZ Sync+Share/Deep Learning for Computer Vision/FinalProject/LearningKeras/KerasCatDog/KerasCatDogPart3.py", line 39, in <module>
    from keras import applications, Model
  File "C:\Users\shaff\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\KerasTensor\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\shaff\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\KerasTensor\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "C:\Users\shaff\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\KerasTensor\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\Users\shaff\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\KerasTensor\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    from .cntk_backend import *
  File "C:\Users\shaff\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\KerasTensor\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\cntk_backend.py", line 2, in <module>
    import cntk as C
  File "C:\Users\shaff\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\KerasTensor\lib\site-packages\cntk\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import cntk_py
  File "C:\Users\shaff\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\KerasTensor\lib\site-packages\cntk\cntk_py.py", line 21, in <module>
    _cntk_py = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\shaff\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\KerasTensor\lib\site-packages\cntk\cntk_py.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_cntk_py')
  File "C:\Users\shaff\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\KerasTensor\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The code I'm running is here and works fine for TensorFlow:

```
from keras import applications, Model
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras import optimizers
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense
import time

# path to the model weights files.
top_model_weights_path = 'bottleneck_fc_model.h5'
# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 150, 150

train_data_dir = 'data/train'
validation_data_dir = 'data/validation'
nb_train_samples = 2000
nb_validation_samples = 800
epochs = 50
batch_size = 16

# build the VGG16 network
base_model = applications.VGG16(include_top=False,weights='imagenet', input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3))
print('Model loaded.')

# build a classifier model to put on top of the convolutional model
top_model = Sequential()
top_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=base_model.output_shape[1:]))
top_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
top_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
top_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# note that it is necessary to start with a fully-trained
# classifier, including the top classifier,
# in order to successfully do fine-tuning
top_model.load_weights(top_model_weights_path)

# add the model on top of the convolutional base
model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=top_model(base_model.output))

# set the first 15 layers (up to the last conv block)
# to non-trainable (weights will not be updated)
for layer in model.layers[:15]:
    layer.trainable = False

# compile the model with a SGD/momentum optimizer
# and a very slow learning rate.
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# prepare data augmentation configuration
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.summary()

# fine-tune the model
t = time.time()  # Track time
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size,
    verbose=1)
print("Fit Generator Time:", time.time() - t)  # Print Elapsed Time
```

I'm running this on Windows 10 using Python 3.6, Keras 2.1.2, and CNTK 2.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late. But there are two solutions to solve this `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cntk._cntk_py'` error.

1) Provide path of the CNTK .dll files location to the System variables. 
2) If it still doesn't solve the problem, Download and Install *Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017*.